# I'm trying to port a make file that was used in linux to be able to work in a windows, confused about some errors

Tags: makefile, stm32

At some point in the make I'm doing this:

```
@copy $(OUTPUT_HEX) $(BUILD_DIR)$(OUTPUT_NAME)_$(VARIANT_MODE)_new.hex
```

As this wasn't working I tried the following command from the same directory:

```
copy /Y build\debug\0821_0822_CON_debug.hex build\debug\hello_new.hex
```

This command is working on cmd, no problem. When I try the same exactly command in the makefile I've got an error saying that the system cannot find the specific route.

So my guess was that for an unknown reason the build is being created from another route, so before running the command I do this:

```
@cd C:/Users/john/git/0821_0822/01_Control/app
@copy /Y build/debug/0821_0822_CON_debug.hex build/debug/hola_app_only.hex
```

Same directory I'm using the copy command in cmd, and it's working there, I don't understand why it's not working.

I've tried some

```
@echo $(CURDIR)
```

Before & after doing the cd, and the directory seems correct, but cd actually doesn't seem to be working, as the diretory is still the same if I change it to another.

I'm really confused about this.

By the way, I'm doing this in ST32CubeIDE, no alternative from what I have to do.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try removing the `@` from these commands, so that it echoes exactly what it is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, pmacfarlane is 100% right.  Using `@`, certainly before your makefile is working 100% correctly, is a bad idea.  You wouldn't try to debug your program by first redirecting all its output to `/dev/null`: this is the equivalent.

The first problem is that this doesn't do what you think it does:

```
@cd C:/Users/john/git/0821_0822/01_Control/app
@copy /Y build/debug/0821_0822_CON_debug.hex build/debug/hola_app_only.hex
```

Every logical line in a makefile recipe is run in a *different shell* which means any changes to the local shell environment (such as setting environment variables, or changing the working directory) are lost whenever the command exits.  So the first command here is a no-op: it starts a shell, changes the directory, exits the shell whereupon the directory change is gone.

Second, writing makefiles in Windows is very tricky because there are so many different possible ways to do things.  Make invokes a shell, but what shell does it invoke?  Is it invoking `cmd.exe`?  Is it invoking Powershell?  Is it invoking a POSIX shell you installed (say as part of Git for Windows)?

That matters because unlike on UNIX systems, many of the programs you run in a Windows shell are built-in to the shell; that includes `copy` for example.  That means that you can't run them as stand-alone programs if you start a different shell.

So it looks to me like your version of `make` is finding UNIX shell `sh.exe` on your PATH, and so it's using that as the shell to invoke commands, and of course that won't allow `copy` to work.

The simplest way around this is to explicitly set the shell you want to run.  For example you can add this to your makefile:

```
SHELL := cmd.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that every command was opening a new shell, that was the missing part for me. The shell isn't a problem, it's actually better if it's opening sh.exe, as this is a port from linux, I'll just leave the original commands and just concatenate a cd before the one that wasn't working.